Kahler geometry and topology in modern physics
How are tools and concepts Complex and algebraic geometry (and also algebraic topology) used in modern physics, such as in string theory? Is there any introductory text which deals with this topic (ie the use of that kind of math in physics) but more addressed to a mathematician?
I am of course not asking for a comprehensive understanding of string theory, instead I just want to understand the kind of tools one uses and maybe also some very basic results and calculations.

This would probably be better asked over on the physics stack exchange.

@BenSteffan I disagree, particularly given that the question is asking for references that are oriented towards mathematicians.

@QuaereVerum "How are [...] used in modern physics?" Is a question primarily addressed to people versed in modern physics, the majority of which will be physicists. I would expect you'd find most of them over on physics stack exchange rather than here.

@BenSteffan People on the physics stackexchange are, in my experience, substantially less likely to provide (or be aware of) the kinds of references that OP is asking for. Better off asking on math.stackexchange, or mathoverflow.

It's very difficult to describe the texts that cover these topics as "introductory", since you are asking about the interactions between different domains of research. As such, one should probably become acquainted with each of these domains separately first, to have a real chance at understanding how they interact.
Secondly, I should make the following disclaimer: the further down this list you go, the more you will go towards the specific topic of mirror symmetry in string theory.
But with those comments out of the way, I would recommend starting with "Geometry, Topology and Physics" by Nakahara. It covers each of topics in the title in some detail and provides extensive applications for them in theoretical physics. There's even a quantum mechanics based proof of the Atiyah-Singer index theorem, which is a very deep mathematical result in and of itself.
There is a book called "Topics in Physical Mathematics" by K. Marathe which gives an overview of differential geometry and topology in physics.
The book "Mathematical Gauge Theory" by M. Hamilton is a good introduction to gauge theory, for mathematicians, by a mathematician.
These texts cover some of the fundamentals, but no algebraic geometry yet. You will (in my estimation) only start to encounter algebraic geometry when you head in the direction of string theory. I've studied mirror symmetry for some time, and the references I now provide are biased in that direction. Starting with "Calabi-Yau Manifolds and Related Geometries" by M. Gross et al., this book contains the basics on Calabi-Yau geometries and then goes on to relate this to mirror symmetry.
There is a paper called "A mini-course on topological strings" by M. Vonk which is found here, and it offers an introduction to the versions of string theory which are most mathematically precise, i.e. topological string theories.
Then there's also the text "Mirror Symmetry" by Hori et al., which can be found at this link in PDF format. There is also its sequel "Dirichlet Branes and Mirror Symmetry" by Aspinwall et al., which focuses on homological mirror symmetry. These texts are the result of collaborations between mathematicians and physicsts. Some of the chapters will look quite foreign to a mathematician, but others will provide great insights.
A book written purely from the algebraic geometry perspective is "Mirror Symmetry and Algebraic Geometry" by D. Cox and S. Katz, and it also contains introductory material (in the appendix), but also assumes some background in algebraic geometry.
